# XCode 3.2 - can't create Objective-C class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

My installation of XCode 3.2 has begun to exhibit some strange behaviour.

When I try to add a basic Objective-C classs (inheriting from NSObject), in my iPhone project, I get the following popup: **"Alert. Couldn't load the next page"**.

The above-mentioned error happens at the point of trying to create the file (i.e. the creation process doesn't get to the stage where you are asked to input the file name). It might also be worth mentioning that where there previously used to be a description for the file (in the file creation window) it now states "No description available".

I can create other files (e.g. UIViewController subclass etc.) but not the basic Objective-C class.

I have updated the documentation and restarted the machine and xcode several times without success.

I would be extremely grateful for any assistance as I am relatively new to the XCode environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen this error before.  Does it happen if you create a new project and try to add a class to it, or only in one particular project?

Comment: It happened even on other projects or new projects. 

For some reason the behaviour has stopped and I can now create the files as before. I'm extremely curious why this would happen though as it was quite frustrating and may happen again in the future.

Comment: If it's happening on a new project, then it sounds to me like your Xocde installation is corrupted.  I would remove it and re-install the developer tools package.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me as well.  If I chose what I wanted the class to inherit from, even though NSObject was already selected, it worked after that.  It did it even after I did a fresh install of XCode.